# How to hide categories in joomla search results

Tags: php, search, joomla

Joomla Search module shows up all the categories which match with the query. For example, if I search "iPhone" on my website, it will display a list of the categories before the list of articles.
I'd like to hide all these categories in the search results.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the administration panel :

```
Menu > Plugin management > Search Categories   (click on unpublihed - green button)
Menu > Plugin management > Indexing Categories (click on unpublihed - green button)
```

Sorry if the labels are not good but I use a french Joomla.

Comment: Not easy for a developer to understand Joomla administration sometimes... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Addition for the search result pages:
The above measurement doesn't disable the display of the category on Joomla search result page.

You can easily hide the category display:

```
.result-category {display: none;}
```

Answer (score -1):

This plug-in following an improved version of the default content search engine! Included in the options you want!

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/improved-content-search

**Compatible only Joomla 3!**

Features:

- Select the mode for category inclusion/exclusion
- Select the categories with a fancy category selector
- Select the mode for article inclusion/exclusion
- Select the articles by article ids
- Limit for the search results
- Can search in archived articles
- Show images for the [Universal AJAX Live Search](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/16893)